# Transforming a string in a list

Tags: python, string, list, integer, tuples

How can I transforms strings in list return a list consisting the elements of strings and the lengths of strings? 
Just like `add_sizes([str]) -> [(str, int)]`

Here is what I did:

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    for i in strings:
        return [(i, (len(i)))]
```

but this only works for one string, What should I do if I have more than one string?

Comment: Could you please add some examples and some code that you have tried

Comment: Question is unclear ? give some appropriate examples.

Comment: @icefish: remove `return` statement outside for loop. check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your mistake

You are returning after you check the first element, hence you will get only the value of the first string. A work around can be

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    temp = []
    for i in strings:
        temp.append((i, (len(i))))
    return temp
```

### Better ways to do it

A better way using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> l = ['abc','defg','hijkl']
>>> map(lambda x:(x,len(x)),l)
[('abc', 3), ('defg', 4), ('hijkl', 5)]
```

And you can define your function as

```
def add_sizes(l):
    return map(lambda x:(x,len(x)),l)
```

Or using a list comp as shown in [Avinash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329672/4099593)

Comment: You will need to catch when the element passed is just a string and not a list of strings, `add_sizes("foo") -> [('f', 1), ('o', 1), ('o', 1)]`

Comment: But Paddy, the OP clearly mentions that it is a list of strings, so most probably he will not need that check :)

Comment: yes indeed, I thought the OP wanted a way that would work for a single string or a list of strings.

Answer (score 4):

Use `list_comprehension`

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar', 'j', 'mn']
>>> [(i,len(i)) for i in l]
[('foo', 3), ('bar', 3), ('j', 1), ('mn', 2)]
```

Defining it as a seperate function.

```
def add_sizes(l):
    return [(i,len(i)) for i in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def add_sizes(strings):
     return list(zip(strings, map(len, strings)))

print(add_sizes(["foo","bar","foobar"])) 

[('foo', 3), ('bar', 3), ('foobar', 6)]
```

If you will have a mixture of lists and single strings you need to catch that:

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    return zip(strings, map(len, strings)) if not isinstance(strings, str) else [(strings, len(strings))]
```

Comment: Better add links to the docs for [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 0):

Use List Comprehension:

```
def add_sizes(slist): 
  out = [(s, len(s)) for s in slist]
  return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct, because `return` statement is inside `for` loop,so during first iteration it will return.

Move `return` statement outside of `for` loop and create new list to add(append) every element and its length as tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> def add_sizes(input_list):
...    result = []
...    for i in input_list:
...        result.append((i, len(i)), )
...    return result
... 
>>> l1 = ["asb", "werg", "a"]
>>> add_sizes(l1)
[('asb', 3), ('werg', 4), ('a', 1)]
>>>
```